# OOP Based TicTacToe - Logic Improvement/Best Practices

Tags: c++, tic-tac-toe

Looking for any feedback to improve practices on the following logic, and I have removed large chunks of documentation to reduce noise. I feel the areas that could expect heavy criticism are the win/tie condition checking.

Main.cpp

```
#include "Board.h"

int main() {
    //initialize board
    Board gameboard;

    for (int i = 0; i < gameboard.GetBoardSize(); i++) {
        gameboard.PlayTurn();
        gameboard.SetTurn(gameboard.GetTurn() + 1);
        if (gameboard.CheckWin()) {
            std::cout << gameboard.GetWin() << " wins!" << std::endl;
            break;
        }
        if (gameboard.CheckTie()) {
            std::cout << "Cat's Game!" << std::endl;
            break;
        }
        if (i == 8) {
            std::cout << "Cat's Game!" << std::endl;
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Board.h

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class Board
{
private:
    std::vector<std::string> tiles;
    int turn;

public:
    //constructors

    Board();

    //getters

    std::string GetTile(int);
    int GetTurn();
    int GetBoardSize();

    //setters

    void SetTile(std::string, int);
    void SetTurn(int);

    //other methods

    void Display();

    void PlayTurn();

    bool CheckPlayedTile(int);

    bool CheckWin();

    bool CheckTie();

    std::string GetWin();
};
```

Board.cpp

```
#include "Board.h"

//constructors
Board::Board() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        tiles.push_back(std::to_string(i));
    turn = 0;
    Display();
}

//getters
std::string Board::GetTile(int pos) {
    return tiles[pos];
}

int Board::GetTurn() {
    return turn;
}

int Board::GetBoardSize() {
    return tiles.size();
}

//setters
void Board::SetTile(std::string letter, int pos) {
    tiles[pos] = letter;
}

void Board::SetTurn(int newTurn) {
    turn = newTurn;
}

//other methods
void Board::Display() {
    std::cout << std::endl;

    if (turn == 0)
        std::cout << "Turn " << turn << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < tiles.size(); i++) {
        if (i % 3 == 0 && i > 0)
            std::cout << std::endl << "---------" << std::endl;
        else if (i % 3 != 0 && i > 0)
            std::cout << " | ";
        std::cout << tiles[i];
    }

    std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;
}

void Board::PlayTurn() {
    int uiTile;

    if (turn % 2 == 0) {
        std::cout << "Turn " << turn << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Player X, please select a square: ";
        std::cin >> uiTile;
        if (!CheckPlayedTile(uiTile))
            tiles[uiTile] = "X";
        else {
            std::cout << uiTile << " has already been played, please select another" << std::endl;
            PlayTurn();
        }

    }
    else {
        std::cout << "Turn " << turn << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Player O, please select a square: ";
        std::cin >> uiTile;
        if (!CheckPlayedTile(uiTile))
            tiles[uiTile] = "O";
        else {
            std::cout << uiTile << " has already been played, please select another" << std::endl;
            PlayTurn();
        }
    }

    Display();
}

bool Board::CheckPlayedTile(int pos) {
    if (tiles[pos] == "X" || tiles[pos] == "O")
        return true;
    return false;
}

bool Board::CheckWin() {
    if (tiles[0] == tiles[1] && tiles[0] == tiles[2])
        return true;//tiles[0];
    else if (tiles[0] == tiles[3] && tiles[0] == tiles[6])
        return true;//tiles[0];
    else if (tiles[0] == tiles[4] && tiles[0] == tiles[8])
        return true;//tiles[0];
    else if (tiles[1] == tiles[4] && tiles[1] == tiles[7])
        return true;//tiles[1];
    else if (tiles[2] == tiles[5] && tiles[2] == tiles[8])
        return true;//tiles[2];
    else if (tiles[2] == tiles[4] && tiles[2] == tiles[6])
        return true;//tiles[2];
    else if (tiles[3] == tiles[4] && tiles[3] == tiles[5])
        return true;//tiles[3];
    else if (tiles[6] == tiles[7] && tiles[6] == tiles[8])
        return true;//tiles[6];
    return false;
}

bool Board::CheckTie() {
    for (int i = 0; i < tiles.size(); i++) {
        if (tiles[i] == "X" || tiles[i] == "O")
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}

std::string Board::GetWin() {
    if (tiles[0] == tiles[1] && tiles[0] == tiles[2])
        return tiles[0];
    else if (tiles[0] == tiles[3] && tiles[0] == tiles[6])
        return tiles[0];
    else if (tiles[0] == tiles[4] && tiles[0] == tiles[8])
        return tiles[0];
    else if (tiles[1] == tiles[4] && tiles[1] == tiles[7])
        return tiles[1];
    else if (tiles[2] == tiles[5] && tiles[2] == tiles[8])
        return tiles[2];
    else if (tiles[2] == tiles[4] && tiles[2] == tiles[6])
        return tiles[2];
    else if (tiles[3] == tiles[4] && tiles[3] == tiles[5])
        return tiles[3];
    else if (tiles[6] == tiles[7] && tiles[6] == tiles[8])
        return tiles[6];
    return "";
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### The interface

When I call `PlayTurn`, I expect the turn counter to automatically increment.

```
gameboard.PlayTurn();
//gameboard.SetTurn(gameboard.GetTurn() + 1);
```

---

Rather than having the end-user do all the logic for the game's end, have a game-over check function. Try something like

```
bool Board::IsGameOver()
std::string Board::GameOverMessage()
```

so that the code will look like

```
if (gameboard.IsGameOver())
    std::cout << gameboard.GameOverMessage();
```

but I still suggest leaving in some of the interface you have, such as the "get winner" and other information state getters if the end-user wants to customize how the information is displayed.

---

### Internal functions

Generally, you don't need to expose state-modifying functions publicly. For example, move functions like `SetTurn` to protected. This way, if the user ever decides to extend tic-tac-toe, he/she can still access the important state-modifying functions without the direct underlying members to mess things up.

---

### Naming

Try to keep naming consistent. In some places, you use Hungarian notation and name variables `uiTurn`, and in others you do lower/UpperCamelCase. Pick something and stick to it.

---

### Logic

Prefer member initialization over member assignment

```
Board::Board(): turn( 0 )
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        tiles.push_back(std::to_string(i));
    Display();
}
```

---

Use an array over a vector if you don't need dynamic allocation.

```
std::array<std::string, 9> tiles;
```

```
for (int i = 0; i < tiles.size(); i++)
    tiles[i] = std::to_string(i);
```

---

`CheckWin` and `GetWin` can be cleaned up by implementing a new function.

```
int WinningRows[8][3]{
{0,1,2}, // horizontal wins
{3,4,5},
{6,7,8},
{0,3,6}, // vertical wins
{1,4,7},
{2,5,8},
{0,4,8}, // diagonal wins
{2,4,6}
};


bool Board::WinningRow(int * rows)
{
    return tiles[rows[0]] == tiles[rows[1]]
           && tiles[rows[0]] == tiles[rows[2]];
}

std::string Board::GetWin() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
        if (WinningRow(WinningRows[i]))
            return GetTile(WinningRows[i][0]);
    return "";
}

bool Board::CheckWin() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
        if (WinningRow(WinningRows[i]))
            return true;
    return false;
}
```

---

Interface functions should abstract implementation details. Rather than numbering each square 0-8 because you have a continuous array, make it take two arguments: x and y.

```
std::string Board::GetTile(int x, int y) {
    return tiles[3*y + x];
}
```

---

`CheckTie` does not make sense to me based on the name -- it looks as though it checks if the board is empty. What does your documentation say? What is its purpose? I'll, for now, assume it is correct.